# Turn off Windows phone 8.1 without power button and Screen

Tags: nokia-lumia-1320

I am using a Windows Lumia 1320. My power button is unresponsive and the screen is frozen. My volume and camera keys are working. Is there any other option to restart?

Comment: Does the power button never work or just when the phone is frozen? have you tried holing the power button + volume down for 10 seconds?

Comment: It never works, I think the board has to replaced.

Comment: @Thomas But is there aby way to switch off using camera and volume buttons, like a long press or something?

Comment: sry, all combinations I know require the power button :-/

Comment: Try detaching the battery!!

Comment: Battery is not detachable for this model.